# Inserting a JavaScript reference into all WordPress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a WordPress MU install (v2.6.2), and I'm trying to figure out how to include a reference to a JavaScript file into all pages served. Research shows me that the key to this is to use wp_enqueue_scripts, but I don't know where to place the call to this.

I think I can achieve what I want by adding the call to header.php for every theme. But is there a single place where I can do this, so I don't have to update each themes header.php file?

I don't require the JavaScript to be included into the admin pages, but it doesn't matter if the solution results in this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress MU was integrated into WordPress itself in version 3.0. The current version as of this post is 3.5.1. I can tell you how to do it in the current version but it might need tweaking to get it working in the version your running.

This would place a script in the header:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'any-name-you-want',
        'url/of/script'
    );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Here's the codex page for [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

*Note: Look into [these functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Available_Functions) when building the URL to your JS file.

You can either add this to every theme's `functions.php` file or save it as a PHP file and use it as a [must use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins). If you want to make it a must use plugin, place it in the **wp-content/mu-plugins** directory and it will run automatically for all sites. In a more current version of WordPress you could also make it a normal plugin and network activate it, but I don't think that option is available in your version.

**With regards to any issues you may encounter related to the version you're running:**

I know `wp_enqueue_script()` was added in 2.6, but I'm not sure about the corresponding `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. If it doesn't work you can try hooking into `init`:

```
add_action('init', 'my_scripts_method');
```

You might even get away with a naked call to `wp_enqueue_script()` without hooking it into an action if `init` doesn't work either. If you have to go with either of these, you should surround it with the following conditional to keep it from being added to your admin screens:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    /* code */
}
```

Honestly, you really should consider upgrading. I know it can be a pain, but there are multiple known security issues in older versions of WordPress. Not to mention some pretty awesome new features.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That gives me a few avenues to explore.

As for the upgrade comment, trust me when I say there are valid reasons for not investigating that route right now.

Comment: Well your init action approach works (the wp_enqueue_scripts one didn't), so I'm going to mark this as the correct answer. Thanks a bunch for your help. However, it has opened up another can of worms. The JavaScript I'm trying to include depends on jQuery, which isn't included in all themes being used. But as its nearly beer o'clock on a Friday arvo, I'll solve that one next week. :-)

Comment: The third parameter for `wp_enqueue_script()` is for declaring dependencies. Try `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'url', array( 'jquery' ) )`. Glad it's working. :)

Comment: While that approach works, it meant I could possibly have JQuery loaded twice, as the default blog theme includes it. But I tweaked the js being referenced to load JQ if it hadn't already been loaded, and I now have a working solution. Thanks again for all your help.